# Bootstrap 5's Tooltip data-bs-title not updating visually, but shows the update in Inspect Element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following JavaScript function:

```
expandCollapse() {
if (this.collapseButtonIconTarget.classList.contains("bi-chevron-compact-down")) {
  this.collapseButtonIconTarget.classList.remove("bi-chevron-compact-down")
  this.collapseButtonIconTarget.classList.add("bi-chevron-compact-up")
  this.collapseButtonIconTarget.setAttribute("data-bs-title", "Expand")
} else {
  this.collapseButtonIconTarget.classList.remove("bi-chevron-compact-up")
  this.collapseButtonIconTarget.classList.add("bi-chevron-compact-down")
  this.collapseButtonIconTarget.setAttribute("data-bs-title", "Collapse")
}
```

}

Which is fired when you click on the collapse/expand button:

```
%button.btn.btn-dark{type: "button", data:{action: "click->uploads#expandCollapse", bs:{toggle: "collapse", target:"#uploadsList"}}}
  %i.bi.bi-chevron-compact-up{data:{uploads_target: "collapseButtonIcon", bs:{toggle: "tooltip", placement: "top", title: "Expand"}}}
```

Visually, when I click on the button, the tooltip "Expand" doesn't get updated.  So I right-clicked on it and selected Inspect Element to check the DOM.  Then I clicked and watched the element's data-bs-title attribute change.

So not sure how to get it to update on the document itself.  The icon part of the code works as expected.

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
    var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
    })
```

I've added the initialize code I have per an answer below, and my comment wondering if I need ot add an Event Listener for when the tooltips change.

**Update**

Providing some screenshots here for context.  I switched it from data-bs-title to the element's plain title for these screenshots.

The Title attribute's tooltip is apparently displaying in addition to the Bootstrap title tooltip, so I'll go back to data-bs-title.  But, these screenshot illustrate that:

The Title attribute is being updated via the JavaScript, but the Bootstrap title isn't.

[image: Expand/Collapse button in the expanded state with "Collapse" in HTML title and "Expand" in bootstrap title]

[image: The same button, but with Expand in both titles when in collapsed state.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bootstrap tooltips, you initialize that element as a tooltip at some point, usually people put this code in the page load, and after they add new tooltip content to the page. So bootstrap's code is set with the tooltip that was present at that time. I don't know if bootstrap has another method you can run to update the tooltip (possibly), or perhaps you can remove the tooltip from the element and then re-add it again, but usually in this situation I see people just put "Expand/Collapse" as the tooltip and leave it.

Comment: To clarify, the "Expand" tooltip does show (as I have the initialization code in place too).  But when you set the attribute via JS, it doesn't "update" it visually but it does in the DOM tree. . . .Now that I think about it I might need to add an Event Listener for when it changes?  I've put the initialize code I have currently in my original question.

Comment: @PatrickVellia I think you're misunderstanding. I know that you ran the init code, since the tooltip is working. what i'm saying is that the code initializes with the initial value when you run the init code. It doesn't suddenly run more code to check the new value whenever you change it and update the tooltip text. it never checks that data value again after the initialization. So you either have to find a way to reinitialize the tooltip after you change the value, or use the easy way, setting it to "Expand/Collapse" and don't mess with it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I understand now and was able to set up the callback to reinitialize it on click.  I use the tooltips on progress bars too, so reinitializing it to be dynamically updated was the way to go for me.